# How do I make the contents of a form output into the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, element

I'm trying to make a form that shows the winner of a contest.
I've been able to make the score of the winner, but not the name of that person.
I used the jquery calx to do the math, but just saying who the winner is has been driving me nuts. I've spent most of the day trying to figure this out.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>

<script src="js/jquery-calx-master/js/numeral.min.js"></script>
  <script src="D:/Catapult Cruzers/web site/js/jquery-calx-master/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="D:/Catapult Cruzers/web site/js/jquery-calx-master/jquery-calx-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#sheet').calx();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>



                                       <form id="sheet">
Pilot <input data-cell="p1" name="Pilot1">
Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A1" />
Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="A2" />
Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A3" />
  Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A4" data-formula="max(A1:A3)" />
  Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A5" data-formula="(sum(A1:A3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />
   <br>
  Pilot <input data-cell="p2" name="Pilot2">
Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B1" />
Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="B2" />
Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B3" />
  Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B4" data-formula="max(B1:B3)" />
  Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B5" data-formula="(sum(B1:B3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />
    <br>
  Pilot <input data-cell="p3" name="Pilot3">
Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C1" />
Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="C2" />
Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C3" />
  Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C4" data-formula="max(C1:C3)" />
  Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C5" data-formula="(sum(C1:C3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />
    <br>
  Pilot <input data-cell="p4" name="Pilot4">
Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D1" />
Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="D2" />
Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D3" />
  Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D4" data-formula="max(D1:D3)" />
  Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D5" data-formula="(sum(D1:D3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />
<br><br>

WINNER   <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="w1" data-formula="MAX(A4:D4)" data-format="0.000" />



WINNER AVE  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="w2" data-formula="MAX(A5:D5)" data-format="0.000" />

</form>




</body>

</html>
```

Along with the scores of the winner and the winner ave (highest average score) I'd like the names of the pilots (p1, p2, p3, p4) to display alongside the score. Something like:

Winner Jimmy 8.52    As it is currently it's just Winner 8.52

Comment: Why are you using a form for that?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?

Comment: It's to figure out a winner. You have this on a tablet or computer. You put in the name of each contestant. as they do a flights, you put in the time. it figures out the best time. I also want it to figure out the winner. There are going to be a LOT more than four though. I'm just using four to figure this out. When you have 30 contestants you want to have this.

Comment: It's jquery. Did I put it in the wrong area? Understand, finding the scores isn't the issue. I can't figure out how to put the winner's name there. I didn't include it because nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris...

I have never use the calx framework so I thought I would answer even though it is almost as I did it all for you. The documentation for calx is not the best but there are some samples on the GitHub subversion.

Make sure you rename the 'Pilot' data-cell to have a uppercase P. Other than that the code below should work just fine for you.

If you take anything away from this post please at least consider the following..

- have cleaner code, proper indentations creates a whole world of better readability
- When you post on Stack you should make sure you read and re-read everything you wrote. (what you have is rather confusing)
- Have fun and make sure you declare me as answering the question!

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>

  <html>
  <head>

      <title>Untitled</title>

      <script src="js/jquery-calx-master/js/numeral.min.js"></script>
      <script src="D:/Catapult Cruzers/web site/js/jquery-calx-master/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="D:/Catapult Cruzers/web site/js/jquery-calx-master/jquery-calx-2.2.0.min.js"></script>


  </head>

  <script>

      var max_user_cell = "D";

      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#sheet').calx();
      });

      function getWinner()
      {
          var sheet = $('#sheet').calx('getSheet')
          var avg_array = new Array();
          var results = document.getElementById('results');
          var winner;
          var highest_avg;

          var count = 0;
          var cell_letter = "A";
          while(count < 4)
          {
              avg_array[count] = sheet.evaluate('(sum(' + cell_letter + '1:' + cell_letter + '3))/3');
              cell_letter = nextChar(cell_letter);
              count++;
          }

          highest_avg = Math.max.apply(Math, avg_array);
          winner = avg_array.indexOf(highest_avg);
          winner++;

          results.innerHTML = sheet.getCellValue('P' + winner) + " is the winner with a time of " + highest_avg.toFixed(2);
      }


      function nextChar(c)
      {
          return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      }

  </script>

  <body>


  <form id="sheet" onchange="getWinner()">

      Pilot <input data-cell="P1" name="Pilot1">
          Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A1" />
          Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="A2" />
          Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A3" />
          Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A4" data-formula="max(A1:A3)" />
          Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="A5" data-formula="(sum(A1:A3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />

      <br>

      Pilot <input data-cell="P2" name="Pilot2">
          Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B1" />
          Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="B2" />
          Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B3" />
          Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B4" data-formula="max(B1:B3)" />
          Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="B5" data-formula="(sum(B1:B3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />

      <br>

      Pilot <input data-cell="P3" name="Pilot3">
          Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C1" />
          Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="C2" />
          Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C3" />
          Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C4" data-formula="max(C1:C3)" />
          Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="C5" data-formula="(sum(C1:C3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />

      <br>

      Pilot <input data-cell="P4" name="Pilot4">
          Run 1    <input   maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D1" />
          Run 2    <input  maxlength="5" size="5"  type="text" data-cell="D2" />
          Run 3    <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D3" />
          Max  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D4" data-formula="max(D1:D3)" />
          Ave  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="D5" data-formula="(sum(D1:D3))/3 " data-format="0.000" />

      <br>
      <br>

      WINNER   <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="w1" data-formula="MAX(A4:D4)" data-format="0.000" />

      WINNER AVE  <input  maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" data-cell="w2" data-formula="MAX(A5:D5)" data-format="0.000" />

      <br>
      <br>

      <span id="results"></span>

  </form>


  </body>

  </html>
  ```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your help! Works like a champ.